# Working with yarn-workspace, specify the package root folder to have a nicer import path

Tags: typescript, package.json, yarn-workspaces

### Context

I am working with `yarn-workspace` and `typescript`.

Consider the following project structure :

```
project/
|- package.json
|- packages/
| |- common/
| | |- build/
| | | `- src/
| | |  |- myFile.d.ts
| | |  `- myFile.js
| | |- package.json
| | `- src/
| |  | `- myFile.ts
| |  `- tsconfig.json
| `- app/
|   |- package.json
|   |- src/
|   | `- index.ts
|   `- tsconfig.json
`- yarn.lock
```

```js
// packages/common/src/myFile.ts
export function functionFromCommon(): void {
  console.log("Greetings from common");
}
```

### Problem

My problem is that, when trying to reference `functionFromCommon` from the "app" folder, I have to write the following :

```js
// packages/app/src/index
import { functionFromCommon } from 'common/build/src/myFile';

functionFromCommon();
```

What I would like is to find a way to only write `import {} from "common/myFile"` when referencing it from other packages.

I know I could bundle all of my common package in a single entry point `index.js` but I would like to keep the folder` structure as it is in order to write:

```js
import { f1 } from "common/moduleA";
import { f2 } from "common/moduleB";
```

I tried to look into what could be specified in the `package.json` (some kind of "mainFolder" field) but couldn't find anything.

### Additional information

For your information, the `package.json` files look like this :

```json
// root package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

```json
// packages/common/package.json
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
  }
}
```

```json
// packages/app/package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
  }
}
```

And the `tsconfig.json` both are like this:

```json
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "incremental": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "types": ["node"],
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./build/tsbuildinfo.json",

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

### Update: (2020-10-13)

A new field called `"exports"` has been added to `package.json` to define just that. See more information here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_exports_sugar.

But it is not currently supported by Typescript...

I was able to have a working version by following this workaround: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079#issuecomment-702617758.

Comment: I'm occurring the same, not TS does suppose to support the `exports` field, but still I'm unable to create a shorted path.. any additional suggestion to what you've created?